# Edit field set description

Tags: object, fieldsets, setup

Is it possible to edit a field set description?

When I go to Field Sets -> (pick a field set) Edit I am able to edit only fields in the Field Sets, but not a description.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on that <kbd>☶ Field Set Properties</kbd> button next to <kbd>Save</kbd>, <kbd>Cancel</kbd>, <kbd>↶ Undo</kbd>, and <kbd>↷ Redo</kbd>.